# How to stop the continuation of posts on the second loop from where the first ended

Tags: loop

I recently built a theme that has slider on the index page that loops through posts to create the content of the slider(used increment to stop at five posts only),  but for some reason that is just above me,the posts on the next loop I used to get latest posts, picks up from where the slider loop ended, does any one have an idea on how to make the second loop start all over from the first post, thanks in advance to any one who will answer.

Comment: We need more information on the slider used etc. pp. Please edit your question and provide such information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add

```
wp_reset_postdata();
```

After your loop that gets the 5 posts for your slider.

Comment: This is correct, whenever you use a `WP_Query` you should *always* add the `wp_reset_postdata()` before your ending `endif;`